# gazebo9 Symbol lookup error

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Removed all gazebo8 related components and installed gazebo9

Getting the following while trying to launch

> gazebo: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsdformat.so.6: undefined symbol: _ZTIN8ignition4math2v45ColorE

**EDIT#1:**

Results from `apt show libignition-math*`

https://pastebin.com/iN82NtLZ

Results from `ldd $(which gazebo)`

https://pastebin.com/4MMz9b4T

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18768/gazebo9-symbol-lookup-error/) by [hvpandya](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4770/hvpandya/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2018-03-13**:
Would you mind posting the output of the following commands?

```
apt show libignition-math*
```

```
ldd $(which gazebo)
```

**Comment by [hvpandya](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4770/hvpandya/) on 2018-03-14**:
@sloretz Edited my OP with results. Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

> libignition-math4.so.4 => /usr/local/lib/libignition-math4.so.4

Looks like at some point `ignition-math4` was installed from source - it has the prefix `/usr/local/lib`. If installed via `apt` it would be in `/usr/lib`.

It probably was built before [this pull request was merged](https://bitbucket.org/ignitionrobotics/ign-math/pull-requests/216/versioned-inline-namespaces/diff). If the build folder is still around then do `sudo make uninstall` to uninstall it. Otherwise you'll have to find and delete its files manually. This list is probably incomplete:

```
/usr/local/share/doc/libignition-math4
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libignition-math4.so.4.0.0
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libignition-math4.so.4
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/ignition-math4/*
/usr/local/include/ignition/math4/*
```

Then I would force reinstall ignition-math4 in case something from it accidentally got deleted

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install libignition-math4*`

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) with karma: 558 on 2018-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvpandya](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4770/hvpandya/) on 2018-03-14**:
On point! I did have an old source install of libignition-math4.

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9644/microbot/) on 2019-07-06**:
can you please help me, I am having similarr gzserver symbol lookup error but for libgazebo_ros_control.so , can you please help me how to fix this ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`sudo apt upgrade`

solve my problem

---

Originally posted by [gop](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14526/gop/) with karma: 21 on 2019-08-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chillbird](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16396/chillbird/) on 2019-09-19**:
worked for me as well. thanks!